# How do you combine two bytearrays in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to combine two ByteArrays to send it out as post data using URLRequest.. Whenever I try to simply add them up, the request becomes GET instead of POST and the data for some reason doesn't get included.

Answer (score 3):

create a total ByteArray by adding other ByteArray objects to it via the [writeBytes()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeBytes%28%29) public method of the ByteArray class.

more info here:  [Reading and writing a ByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d54.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Combining / Concatination Two Byte Arrays**

```
Var Data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
Var Salt:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var DataAndSalt:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                    DataAndSalt.length = (Data.length + Salt.length);//Defines the **length of Resultant Array**
                //Array Copy Method(VB)/ Concate the ByteArray(ActionScript) one After another  
                    DataAndSalt.writeBytes(Data);
                    DataAndSalt.writeBytes(Salt);
```

I will Show here Conversion of String into Byte Array and **Merging Them (concate /combining)** them into single **byte array**

```
// In Detail


            var HashOut:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var byterrData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var byterrSalt:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

        //conversion of string Data and Salt in respective (UTF-8 and Default) Byte Array   

     var Data:String = "password";
              var Salt:String ="‰ô©³¶í";  //Using Special Characters in a String variable 

            byterrData.writeMultiByte(Data, "iso-8859-1");
            byterrSalt.writeMultiByte(Salt,Salt);

var DataAndSalt:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                DataAndSalt.length = (Data.length + Salt.length);
            // Concate the ByteArray    
                DataAndSalt.writeBytes(Data);
                DataAndSalt.writeBytes(Salt);

//Now You can Trace It by using 

trace(DataAndSalt[0]);
trace(DataAndSalt[index Number]);
```

Comment: You should have sticked to demoing the "writeBytes()" method of the ByteArray. The rest of your code is irrelevant to the OP's question.

Answer (score -4):

Not sure what your code looks like... the GET/POST issue is very weird.

However, use the below instead of trying to "add them up" (whatever that means).

```
array3 = array1.concat(array2);
```

Comment: Argh! You're right. In that case he can create a new ByteArray, and writeBytes the first then the second arrays into the new one. My bad though.